# How to search into JSON using REST assured GPath

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

I have following JSON

{
"resourceType": "Parameters",
"parameter": [
{
"name": "result",
"valueBoolean": true
},
{
"name": "message",
"valueString": "Matches found"
},
{
"name": "match",
"part": [
{
"name": "equivalence",
"valueCode": "equivalent"
},
{
"name": "concept",
"valueCoding": {
"system": "http://my.org/fhir/CodeSystem/locationrep",
"code": "LOC1"
}
},
{
"name": "source",
"valueUri": "http://my.org/fhir/ConceptMap/locationrep"
}
]
}
]
}

I need to extract LOC1 value. I use .get("resp.content,"parameter.find {parameter -> parameter.name == 'match'}.part[1].valueCoding.code") with success but the index array of the object will be change.